# PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_128 and AES Modes like GCM

Tags: java, cryptography, passwords, aes

First of all I have successfully written code using Java (JDK 8) for encryption and decryption that uses `PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_128`.

But I am wondering if it's AES then how can I use mode like GCM to check integrity.

On other hand - I am able to use `AES/GCM/NoPadding` in conjunction with `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256`. Means key is generated using `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256` and used in AES/GCM.

1. But I am struggling to find sources that generate key using `PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_128` and use AES/GCM
   Or even if it's possible or if it makes sense?
2. Secondly the key generated using `PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_128` is always 9 bytes - if it's the case then I am wondering AES 128 needs key of size 16 bytes and how key is getting generated as 9 bytes?

Any help / clarification in this regards is highly appreciated ...

Code using `PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_128`

```
private byte[] getRandomNumber(final int size) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
    byte[] randomBytes = new byte[size];
    secureRandom.nextBytes(randomBytes);
    return randomBytes;
}


private SecretKey getPBE_AES_Key(final String password, final byte[] salt) {
    try {
        char[] passwdData = password.toCharArray();

        PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passwdData, salt, 4096, 128);
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128");
        SecretKey pbeKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
        return pbeKey; // <-- size of this byte array is 9 - I thought it should be 16 since its AES 
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException ex) {
        throw new OperationFailedException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}


public String encrypt_PBE_AES(final String plaintext, final String password) {
    try {
        byte[] ivBytes = getRandomNumber(16);
        byte[] saltBytes = getRandomNumber(16);
        byte[] dataToEncrypt = plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128");
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
        PBEParameterSpec pbeParameterSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(saltBytes, 4096, ivParameterSpec);

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getPBE_AES_Key(password, saltBytes), pbeParameterSpec);
        byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(dataToEncrypt);

        byte[] ivWithSalt = ArrayUtils.addAll(ivBytes, saltBytes);
        byte[] encryptedDataWithIVAndSalt = ArrayUtils.addAll(ivWithSalt, encryptedData);
        String encodedData = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedDataWithIVAndSalt);
        return encodedData;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException
        | BadPaddingException | IOException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException ex) {
        throw new OperationFailedException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}

public String decrypt_PBE_AES(final String ciphertext, final String password) {
    try {
        byte[] encryptedDataWithIVAndSalt = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(ciphertext);
        byte[] ivBytes = ArrayUtils.subarray(encryptedDataWithIVAndSalt, 0, 16);
        byte[] saltBytes = ArrayUtils.subarray(encryptedDataWithIVAndSalt, 16,
            16 + 16);
        byte[] dataToDecrypt = ArrayUtils.subarray(encryptedDataWithIVAndSalt,
            16 + 16, encryptedDataWithIVAndSalt.length);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128");
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
        PBEParameterSpec pbeParameterSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(saltBytes, 4096, ivParameterSpec);

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getPBE_AES_Key(password, saltBytes), pbeParameterSpec);
        byte[] decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(dataToDecrypt);

        return new String(decryptedData, "UTF-8");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | UnsupportedEncodingException
        | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException ex) {
        throw new OperationFailedException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}
```

As you can see there are 2 questions ...

**a)** In my code i am keeping IV and salt with ciphertext. I wanted to use AES/GCM to check integrity of entire IV + salt.

**b)** Why the byte [] of key is 9 bytes? (When I give input as `Pree@2017` the key generated is 9 bytes - I have check the length of `pbeKey.getEncoded()` and its 9.

Many Thanks

**Update** - The first question is answered below. However the second question got answered at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/46849/pbewithhmacsha512andaes-128-and-aes-modes-like-gcm

Thanks Everyone !

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Did you know you can format your inline code using back-tick characters? `\`code\`` <- these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On other hand - I am able to use `AES/GCM/NoPadding` in conjunction with `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256`.

Perfect. You seem to want to default to AES-128. When implemented correctly, there is very little wrong with above, and changing to SHA-512 won't help you much (if anything) security-wise.

> But I am struggling to find sources that generate key using PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_128 and use AES/GCM Or even if it's possible or if it makes sense?

AES_128 already indicates that the mode doesn't use integrity. It's kind of an all-or-nothing scheme which defaults to CBC. I'd just keep with what you have, as indicated above.

> Secondly the key generated using PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_128 is always 9 bytes - if it's the case then I am wondering AES 128 needs key of size 16 bytes and how key is getting generated as 9 bytes?

That cannot be right. Undoubtedly the key is 128 bits / 16 bytes, but you're just getting the wrong information, e.g. by trying to directly print out the underlying byte array instead of first converting it to hexadecimals.

Comment: Obviously you need to show your code before I can make any more precise remarks on the second question.

Comment: Thanks for responding @maarten-bodewes  ... I have added the code block and rephrased the 2 questions ... Secondly are you saying that when using `PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_128 ` in Java we DO NOT have any mechanism to use GCM? If this is the case then I will just have to fall back to HMAC for itegrity check of IV + salt when using `PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_128` ... Makes sense?